# How to show the icon of only active box by clicking on this box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see image, I'll have to show the arrow icon by clicking on the box, I have tried but right now it's showing in all boxes.

How do I make it individually shown for each box?
[image]

This is my code

```
 $('.date-box').click(function(){
    $('.date-box').removeClass('active-item');
    $(this).addClass('active-item');
    $('.next-icon').show();
  });
```

Comment: Please share your html as well..

Comment: `$(this).find('.next-icon').show();` only show the icon of curren element

Comment: try this, $(this).closest('.next-icon').show();

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you only want to show the icon in the box that is currently clicked, like you did with the active-class.
Example: `$('.next-icon', this).show();`

Answer (score 0):

`$('.next-icon').show()` will show all elements that have the class `next-icon`. You need to specify in what scope do you want to find that class.

Try using this if `next-icon` class lies within `date-box`

```
$('.date-box').click(function(){
    $('.date-box').removeClass('active-item');
    $(this).addClass('active-item');

    // Hiding all and showing just the current one
    $('.next-icon').hide();
    $(this).find('.next-icon').show();
});
```

Comment: @naresh Please mark the answer if it solved your problem :)